# What is the meaning of the last two bytes of a sector in NTFS filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, ntfs

I have noticed that the last two bytes of an NTFS sector behave on unpredictable way.Sometimes, they not relate to the context.For example, here are the last 8 bytes of a sector.It is a run list.

```
 41 01 80 CB 92 00 E7 09
```

The function that reads run lists parsed E7 as being the data run header , so it returned a very hug value.

Also, some empty sectors only have the last two bytes filled.

Comment: By sector, do you mean MFT entry (file record)?

Comment: I mean the last two bytes of a sector that is part of MTF entry because usually every MTF entry is two sectors long.

Answer (score 0):

The last two bytes of a sector occupied by an MFT entry are used for consistency checks. The data that should reside here is stored in Fixup arrays instead. (Somewhere in the header)